# How to restrict virtual directory access to specific IP IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I checked google but couldn't find anything about that.
How is it possible to restrict virtual directory access to specific IP Address on iis7.5?

Answer (score 2):

In IIS 7.0 a "security" element was added to the web.config schema. It has a child element "ipSecurity" which allows IP-based restrictions. An address to block is listed with the "add" element, or you can set "allowUnlisted" to false (default is true) and the effect is reversed to allow the listed addresses. The following placed in the directory you want to protect will restrict access to localhost and the 192.168.0.0/24 network:

```
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
            <clear />
            <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" />
            <add ipAddress="192.168.0.1" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
         </ipSecurity>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
```

Note that using this feature requires the "IP and Domain Restrictions" IIS role service to be installed. For more details, see the [IIS Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity).

Answer (score -1):

You didn't look very far: Start the IIS manager MMC, select your folder and you'll see "IP address and domain restriction" in the middle pane, in the "IIS" section. Double-click on that and the then:

- Press "Edit feature settings..." in the right pane and set "access for unspecified clients" to "Deny"
- Press "Add Allow Entry..." in the right pane and type in the IP or IP range you want to allow.

Voilà

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Web Platform Installer (https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to install the plugin with "IP address and domain restriction" to be able to do this.

Comment: Please try to avoid link only answers, be more specific and detailed. When you can answer, try to feel like a teacher.