# How do you stop users directly accessing files on a website in IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net, iis-8

I want to stop users on the internet being able to enter this URL into a browser and access these files directly. How can I do this?

for example:
  mysite/uploadedfiles/file1.txt

is there any iis rule? Please help me.

Comment: Why is it in the web directory if you don't want used to access it????

Comment: it's old project, now we caonn't change that,  all uploaded files they are putting into uploadedfiles folder inside a project.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/505333/200560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is ambiguous, but a simple way would be to:

1. Go to content view of the site, right click the file, click edit permissions, click on security tab and edit the permissions to remove IIS_IUSRS

Comment: How can the iis user upload the file without access

Answer (score 1):

If your txt files are not meant to be directly delivered to the users via HTTP and they are just accessed by your application logic, you should move them to a different location, not directly published by IIS.
This could need some reengineering work.
A temporary workaround could be setting up some kind of filtering based on HTTP-REFERRER.

Check this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdevelopertips/2008/12/15/tip-34-did-you-know-how-to-stop-hot-linking-from-your-site-using-url-rewrite-in-iis-7-0/